# `answers` is not invoked when mocking a method with `call-by-name` parameter

Tags: mocking, mockito, specs2, callbyname

There is a class `InvokeLater`, the definition is like:

```
class InvokeLater {
    def apply(f: => Any): Unit = { 
       // do something ...
       f 
       // do some other thing
    }
}
```

In specs test, I mocking it like:

```
val invokeLater = mock[InvokeLater]
invokeLater.apply(any) answers { f => f:Unit }
```

But it seems the code inside `answers` never runs.

Does specs2 support this feature now?

Comment: Can you please validate this answer if it is correct?

Comment: Sorry @Eric, I will give you a clear reply today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that `specs2-mock.jar` is placed before `mockito.jar` on your classpath. Then be aware that the `f` passed to the `answers` method is a `Function0`. For example

```
class InvokeLater {
  def apply(f: =>Int): Unit = {
    // do something ...
    f
    // do some other thing
  }
}

val invokeLater = mock[InvokeLater]

invokeLater.apply(any) answers { f =>
  println("got the value "+f.asInstanceOf[Function0[Int]]())
}

invokeLater.apply(1)
```

This prints:

```
got the value 1
```

Comment: I made a repo here: https://github.com/freewind/specs2-test/blob/master/src/test/scala/my/HelloWorldSpec.scala . It did run the code inside `invokeLater` this time, but the test is still failed, please see the README there

Comment: This is a lot more complex use case, calling a mock inside an answer of a method with byname arguments. I don't know why there are more calls than necessary but you can relax the constraint with `there was atLeastOne(printString).apply("hello world")` as a work around.

Comment: Great that it's helping, a little "tick" to validate the answer then :-)?

Comment: yes, `atLeastOne` is working, but I hope I can write `one`, because `atLeastOne` is a different requirement from `one`

Comment: There might be a solution to this problem but I don't have time for now to really investigate it because this is a complex setup (and I am already doing lots of trickery with Mockito). My advice: refactor the code so that you don't require a stub actioning a mock (if possible).